# AudioVideoCaptureDevice throws an exception (value does not fall within the expected range)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, video-capture

When I call the `StartRecordingToStreamAsync(IRandomAccessStream stream)` method of `AudioVideoCaptureDevice`, it throws an exception

> value does not fall within the expected range

I passed it the correct argument which is an `IRandomAccessStream`. Does any one know how to go about it or suggestions?

here's my code

```
storageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("VideoCrome", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
using (stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    await cam.StartRecordingToStreamAsync(stream);
}
```

Comment: Have you given permissions to Camera device in the App Manifest?

Comment: of course, I have @AndréMeneses